# Python Tkinter Change width of window to longest Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Currently I have: `root.outpt.geometry("360x120")`

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of: `root.outpt.geometry((char_choice.get()*10)x(120))`. What this is meant to do is set the width of the window to `char_choice.get()*10`. `char_choice` being a tkinter variable which is the number of characters selected.

Comment: You know how the use `geometry()`, so what is your problem?

Comment: `root.outpt.geometry((char_choice.get()*10)x(120))` doesn't work. `root.outpt.geometry((360)x(120))` doesn't work either. Only `root.outpt.geometry("360x120")` works, which I cannot use in the equation.

Comment: you can use a [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) root.outpt.geometry(f"{char_choice.get()*10}x{120}")

Comment: First what is `char_choice`? An `Entry`? A `StringVar` or `IntVar`?

Comment: If it is `IntVar` then use `geometry(f"{char_choice.get()*10}x120")`, otherwise `geometry(f"{int(char_choice.get())*10}x120")`.

Comment: This worked. I forgot to send 5 hours ago. Sorry. Thanks for the help guys